# Why does </br> add a line break (in Google Chrome at least)

Tags: html

I know that `<br>` tags are self closing, i.e. they'd be typically written as `<br>` or `<br />`

Out of curiosity, a friend tried `a<br>b</br>c` which resulted, in Google Chrome, in the same as `a<br />b<br />c`, i.e. `</br>` became a line break.

We tried a non-existent closing tag, i.e. `</potato>` and that did not add a line break (or anything). But the `</br>` did. Why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a disturbingly common error and browsers are in the business of doing their best to render webpages, not enforcing the rules of valid HTML.

The [parsing rules](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody:parse-errors-34) call this out explicitly:

> **An end tag whose tag name is "br"**
>
> Parse error. Drop the attributes from the token, and act as described in the next entry; i.e. act as if this was a "br" start tag token with no attributes, rather than the end tag token that it actually is.

Comment: This follows suit with other items as well.  Like mis-indented tags `<b><p></b></p>` and *unclosed* elements like `<p>` where there is clear HTML rules for being "valid", however browsers would be remised if they didn't attempt to "clean up" after invalid HTML.